# Display checkbox next to label (change order)

Tags: html, css

Im trying to align my checkboxes next (on the left) to their label.
My `HTML` structure is managed by Joomla, so I can't edit that.
I can add new `css`, unfortenately my `css` knowledge doesn't reach that far to solve this.

```css
.control-label, .controls{
  display: inline-flex;

}
```

```html
<div id="contactfilter" uk-dropdown="mode: click; pos: bottom-right;" >
  <div id="list1" class="dropdown-check-list">
    <div class="items uk-nav uk-nav-secondary" id="root">
      <a style="
        ">
        <div class="control-group">
          <div class="control-label"><label id="filter_login-lbl" for="filter_login">
            show accounts</label>
          </div>
          <div class="controls">
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input type="checkbox" name="filter[login]" id="filter_login" class="form-check-input" value="1" checked="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a>
        <div class="control-group">
          <div class="control-label"><label id="filter_admin-lbl" for="filter_admin">
            show Admins</label>
          </div>
          <div class="controls">
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input type="checkbox" name="filter[admin]" id="filter_admin" class="form-check-input" value="1">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <button type="submit" class="uk-button uk-button-small uk-button-default uk-align-center">Filter
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me out?
How can I switch the order so my label is on the right next to the checkboxes without changing my `HTML`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `display:flex` to parent class that contain the different element to display in flex layout

then you can invert checkbox and label with `flex-direction: row-reverse;`

to align item on left you can finally use `justify-content: start;`

```css
.control-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: start;
}
```

```html
<div id="contactfilter" uk-dropdown="mode: click; pos: bottom-right;" >
  <div id="list1" class="dropdown-check-list">
    <div class="items uk-nav uk-nav-secondary" id="root">
      <a style="
        ">
        <div class="control-group">
          <div class="control-label"><label id="filter_login-lbl" for="filter_login">
            show accounts</label>
          </div>
          <div class="controls">
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input type="checkbox" name="filter[login]" id="filter_login" class="form-check-input" value="1" checked="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a>
        <div class="control-group">
          <div class="control-label"><label id="filter_admin-lbl" for="filter_admin">
            show Admins</label>
          </div>
          <div class="controls">
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input type="checkbox" name="filter[admin]" id="filter_admin" class="form-check-input" value="1">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <button type="submit" class="uk-button uk-button-small uk-button-default uk-align-center">Filter
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to display the checkboxes on the left side oof the labels, is that possible too?

Comment: yes it's possible with justify-content and flex-direction i edit my reply in consequencies